# rxjs: Does forkJoin need at least one call to next to complete?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have two observables which I would like to forkJoin:

```
  var goodObservable = Rx.Observable.create( function(observer){
    observer.next('something');
    observer.complete();
  });

  var badObservable = Rx.Observable.create( function(observer){
    observer.complete();
  });


  var forkJoinedObservable = Rx.Observable.forkJoin([goodObservable, badObservable]);  

  forkJoinedObservable.subscribe(function(results){
    console.log(results);
  });
```

One of those observables only calls complete. Now I have found that the forkJoined observables never gets triggered. I will have to call observer.next() in the badObservable in order to make the subscription on forkJoin to be executed.

My expected behaviour would be that the forkJoin-subscribes would be executed with an array containing just one item: ['something']

Is this a bug, or did I not understand the concept correctly?

I have made a plunkr for this: https://plnkr.co/edit/QaA9DwyWAmTGbthvguPK?p=preview

Comment: forkJoin() emits the *last* emitted item from each observable. There's no item to emit in this case.

Comment: but shouldn't the call to observer.complete() trigger the forkJoin, since the other observers did produce values?

Comment: Nope, everything needs to emit and complete for forkJoin to work.  Fork joins interface is such that it returns an array matching it's arguments, so it cannot return an array shorter than it's arguments.  If each item doesn't emit, then it needs to make an assumption about what should be there (null? undefined?), which it shouldn't have to do.  You can restructure things easily to achieve what you seem to be after using concat instead of forkjoin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forkJoin()` emits the last emitted item from each observable. There's no item to emit in this case, so the operator doesn't emit.

A pragmatic solution would be to call `.startsWith(defaultValue)` on each observable, so `forkJoin()` can complete as well.

```
var goodObservable = Rx.Observable.create( function(observer){
  observer.next('something');
  observer.complete();
});

var badObservable = Rx.Observable.create( function(observer){
  observer.complete();
}).startWith(null);


var forkJoinedObservable = Rx.Observable.forkJoin([goodObservable, badObservable]);  

forkJoinedObservable.subscribe(function(results){
  console.log(results);
});
```

About emitting values just for the observables that have emitted, this wouldn't work, because then you wouldn't know which one didn't emit. Of course, it could have emitted `null`. But given this is achievable by combining operators, I don't think it's gonna change.